# Template function type deduction and operator<<

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, reference, template-argument-deduction

When I compile the following code with **MSVC++**, I get an error:

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator<<(T&& x)
    {
    }

};
void f()
{
}
int main()
{
    A().operator<<( f );  // ok
    A() << f;             // error

    return 0;
}
```

**g++** and **clang** both compile this code fine.
AFAIK, '**ok**' and '**error**' lines do exactly the same thing, and type **T** is deduced to **void(&)()**. Or is it **void()** and rvalue references to function are allowed? If so, what is their meaning?
Is it ok to pass functions by reference like that? Is it **MSVC++** bug that it fails to compile '**error**' line? BTW, the error output:

```
no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
could be 'void A::operator <<<void(void)>(T (__cdecl &&))'
with[ T=void (void) ]
```

Comment: can you provide the version of your c++ compiler?

Comment: MSVC++2012 with NOV CTP update, gcc 4.5.3 and 4.7.2 tested, clang 3.0 and 3.1 tested.

Comment: I don't have VC11, so it's hard for me to investigate, but it smells like a bug with URef collapsing. The compiler mistakenly interprets it as an RRef to function and does not accept an lvalue in input. It would be interesting to check whether `typedef void (* test)(); test g() { return f; } ... A() << g();` would work

Comment: function pointers do work, I checked that already, using &f instead of f when doing << call

Comment: @dsi: That's not related to `&f` being a function pointer IMO: I think it works because `&f` is an rvalue. If you passed an lvalue, it would not work. Like `test* t = &f; A() << t;`. Is this the case?

Comment: @AndyProwl All of the following do work:
`typedef void (*testp)();
typedef void (&testr)();

testr gr() { return f; }
testp gp() { return f; }

A() << gr();
A() << gp();
testr tr = f;
testr tp = f;
A() << tr;
A() << tp;`

Comment: @dsi: OK, I give up investigating then. Anyway it looks like a bug report would be deserved.

Comment: OK, I filed a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778613)

Comment: Yes, `T` should be deduced (in both statements) as `void (&)()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, answering my own question:

The code provided is valid and while rvalue references to functions are allowed (they act identical to lvalue references), here during template deduction T should become void(&)().

A [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778613) in MSVC prevents my code from compiling.

*UPDATE*: The bug has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013 compiler

Answer (score 4):

Why `void operator<<(T&& x)`?  `void operator<<(T& x)` serves the purpose.

Function can be called with `x()` inside overloaded function as below

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator<<(T& x)
    {
        x();
    }

};
void f()
{
}

int main()
{
    A().operator<<( f );
    A() << f;             
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I use rvalue reference so that temporary _function objects_ would be moved, not copied. For _functions_ either way will work the same though.